# Error with adding custom data source

Tags: vb.net, xaml, windows-phone-8, datasource

Currently in the middle of completing this little app I'm making and I've come across this little error. I've currently made my own Listbox data template and I have binded them but i get an error saying that there is an invalid cast exception. 
My binded Listbox template is:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
    <Grid Height="59" Width="306">
        <TextBlock x:Name="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="306"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Message" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="306" Margin="0,29,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The vb code is:

```
Dim myStore As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    Dim directory As String = "./PENCIL/Notes/*.*"
    Dim filenames As String() = Storage.GetFileNames(directory)
    Dim dataSource As New List(Of SampleData1)()
    dataSource.Add(New SampleData1() With {.Name = filenames(directory)})
    ItemsList.ItemsSource = dataSource
```

This is basically supposed to load the files into the listbox.

And my SampleData1 is:

```
 Public Class SampleData1
    Private _name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I keep getting the error at this:

```
dataSource.Add(New SampleData1() With {.Name = filenames(directory)})
```

Look at the picture for a better preview of the error i keep getting:
http://puu.sh/5VGgj.png

is anybody able to help?
Thanks!

Comment: make sure that filenames(directory) returning you a string..

Comment: you are assigning a value to Name property that should be string so your method filenames(directory) should return an string..